# Solving Recursion in fibonacci numbers

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci

I'm unaware of the mathematics in this algorithm and could use some help.

Algorithm:

```
if n<2 then

  return n

else return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

Statement

n < 2 is O(1)
Time n >=2 is O(1)
Return n is O(1)
Time n>=2 is -
Return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) is -

and time n>=2 is T(n-1) + T(n-2) +O(1)

Total: O(1) T(n-1) + T(n-2) + O(1)
T(n) =  O(1) if n < 2
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + O(1) if n>=2

Comment: There are 2 recursive calls in the function. At best, your depth of recursive is n/2, giving 2^kn (with k = 1/2). I suspect this isn't good enough - which is why it's a comment, not an answer. I will say, though, that GHC for Haskell will (I believe) automatically optimise this by memoising intermediate results (implicit dynamic programming), giving O(n). Yes, I know this isn't Haskell syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're supposed to notice that the recurrence relation for this function is *awfully familiar*. You can learn exactly how fast this *awfully familiar* recurrence grows by looking it up by name.

However, if you fail to make the intuitive leap, you can try to bound the runtime using a simplified problem. Essentially, you modify the algorithm in ways guaranteed to increase the runtime while making it simpler. Then you figure out the runtime of the new algorithm, which gives you an upper bound.

For example, this algorithm must take longer and is simpler to analyze:

```
F(n): if n<2 then return n else return F(n-1) + F(n-1)
```

Comment: right - the answer is right in your face, particular if you know how fast fibonacci numbers grow!

Answer (score 3):

By induction: if calculation of `fib(k)` takes less than `C*2^k` for all `k < n`, for the calculation tome of `fib(n)` we've got

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + K < C*2^(n-1) + С*2^(n-2) + K
     = 0.75*C*2^n + K < C*2^n
```

for sufficiently big `C` (for `C > K/0.25`, as `2^n > 1`). This proves that `T(n) < C*2^n`, i.e. `T(n) = O(2^n)`.

(Here `T(n)` is the time for calculation of `fib(n)`, `K` is the constant time needed for calculating `fib(n)` when both `fib(n-1)` and `fib(b-1)` are [already] calculated.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve the recurrence equation:

```
T(0) = 1
T(1) = 1
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2), for all n > 1
```

Comment: My that's familiar...
Don't forget T(1) = 1.